# Pythonで、使っている(通過する)関数と使っていない関数を区別したい。

Tags: python

```
def myTasu(myA,myB):
    return myA+myB
def myHiku(myA,myB):
    return myA-myB
print("#",myTasu(1,2))
# 3
```

①関数を数える。2個
②myTasuは通過する。myHikuは通過しない。

おすすめのアプリを教えて下さい。
サクラエディタのgrepを繰り返す事しか思いつきませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

`pytest`に下記のプラグインを追加してみるといいかもしれません。
[pytest-func-cov · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-func-cov/)

`pytest`についてご存じなければ検索して調べてください。

（私はご教授できるほど経験はありません）